# svelte-preprocess does not transform typescript into javascript

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-preprocess

I am trying to parse svelte component source codes in web worker.
Full source code [here](https://github.com/wangjia184/svelte-parser/blob/master/src/worker.ts)

```
import { parse , preprocess } from 'svelte/compiler';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

import {
  typescript,
  scss,
  globalStyle,
} from 'svelte-preprocess';


async function parseSvelte(source : string) {
  
  const preprocessedResult = await preprocess( source, [
    typescript({}),
    scss(),
    globalStyle(),
  ]);
  console.log(preprocessedResult);

  try {
  const ast = parse(preprocessedResult.code);
  console.log(ast);
  }
  catch(e) { console.log(e.toString() )}
}
```

I am using the above code to parse the following svelte component

```
<script lang="ts">
const x = (y : string) => {};
</script>
```

`preprocess` should transform the typescript into javascript, right?
But `preprocessedResult.code` still contains typescript, and the subsequent `parse` failed.

```
Unexpected token (3:25)
1: 
2:           <script lang="ts">
3:             const x = (y : string) => {};
                            ^
4:             </script>
```

There is no error when calling `preprocess` method, please what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in [svelte-preprocess/src/transformers/typescript.ts](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/blob/main/src/transformers/typescript.ts) line 497
`if (filename == null) return { code: content };`

When you call svelte.preprocess without the "optional" filename the typescript preprocessor does nothing.

Call preprocess with the third argument to fix the issue:

```
svelte.preprocess(code, processors, { filename: '/path/to/Component.svelte' })
                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

(It doesn't even have to be a valid filename)

I've reported the bug https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/issues/488